# Android 4.0 Design Guidelines

Tags: android

I am really frustrated by all the Android apps in the market that look like iPhone apps. What is a good place for Android design guidelines for Android 4.0 Phones and Tablets?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://developer.android.com/design

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel your pain. But we're in luck!

I found this last week, Google's own design guidelines:
http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

In particular, this is a good reference for the differences between platforms.
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Google just released [this](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Another good source, next to the already mentioned Google Design Guide Graham and DeebV, is the [Android Interaction Design Patterns](http://www.androidpatterns.com/) website.